# is there a way to detect if the contextMenu is open in android?

Tags: android, contextmenu

The questions in the title, had a look around but couldnt find any answers,

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting a boolean in

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

and then unsetting it in

```
@Override
public void onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);
}
```

Comment: thanks craigy, I didnt use it as I found the GestureDetector.onSingleTapUp method that meant I didn't need to have any workarounds (I am using a horizontal scroll view with full screen views within) I was hoping for a cleaner solution but mark as right unless anything cleaner comes along